# Change navigation bar if user is logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, navigation

I want the "Login/Sign up" button in the navigation bar to change to "My Account" after the user logs in. I have a problem as my index.html page does not display the navigation bar.

index.html page:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Index Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

navigation.php

```
<?php 
include("check.php");   
?>


<?php 
if ($loginst == 1){ ?>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul >               
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="account.php">My Account</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul >               
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="login.php">Login</a</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

check.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();
$loginst = 0;
if ($_SESSION['username']){ 

$user_check = $_SESSION['username'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['username'];

if(!empty($login_user)) 
{
   $loginst = 1;
}   
}

?>
```

If I go to index.html then nav bar is not displayed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: On a side note, you have a potential security vulnerability in your query. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
and I would recommend using PDO with prepared statements whenever doing queries: https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your file format is html and does not support php tags :

```
<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
```

rename index.html to index.php for support php include.